# PostgreSQL Docker connection error - "no encryption"

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run a PostgreSQL database on a Docker container while allowing outside connections to it. I am using the "official" PostgreSQL Docker image (version 13).
After running the image, exposing its 5432 port, and mapping the container's 5432 port to the host's 5432 port I am greeted with the following error when trying to connect to it:

`Fatal error: np pg_hba.conf entry for host "my_ip", user "admin", database "postgres", no encryption.`

I've looked everywhere for a solution but all the answers are the same, so I will write here what has been suggested and I already did (or existed already):

1. The line: `listen_addresses = '*'` is in the file `postgresql.conf`.
2. The line `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` is in the file `pg_hba.conf`.
3. Ran the image with `--expose 5432` and `-p 5432:5432`.

I've also tried adding the lines: `host all all ::1/128 md5` && `host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 md5` in `pg_hba.conf` (with AND without `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`).

I'm at a loss of what to do or try next - can anyone please suggest something to solve this pickle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you reload the config files after changing them?  What do you find in the db server's  log files?

Comment: I reloaded the database after I made sure the config files are as necessary. The log files show nothing - it's just running with no errors.

Comment: I would suggest your port forwarding failed because there was something else already listening/forwarding on that port.  So you are trying to connect to a different database than you want, which means you rely on a different pg_hba and the failure is logged to a different logfile.

Comment: I figured it out: I was using Docker on Windows (Docker desktop) to test stuff out and apparently it changes the port forwarding of localhost to some custom Docker site in the hosts file (system32). I switched to my Linux system and worked fine straight out of the box...